# Regex all characters except string

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want to select all space characters except those preceded by the string, `Send,`.

A look-ahead using `(?!)` will not work. What is another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like look *behind* should suffice. If the string `Send,` immediately precedes the the space you want then it would be:

```
(?<!Send,)\s
```

If the string doesn't come directly before the space then your options could depend a bit on your particular regex flavour, since many do not support variable length look behinds.